# jquery synchronous post

Tags: jquery, ajax

On jquery website they tell you that you can do this:

```
jQuery.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url:    'http://example.com',
     success: function(result) {
              },
     async:   false
});
```

And this will make this call synchronous

but what if I am using the jquery format to post:

```
     $.post( '../php/x.php', {},
     function( data ){  // a function to deal with the returned information
        }

    }, "json");
```

How can I make this synchronous?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You probably shouldn't be making it synchronous anyway, [but you can't](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/).  An approximation would be

```
$.ajaxSetup({async: false});
$.post();
```

Comment: Why not :$ my problem is that I have a jquery function that is executed on a form's submit. Now within it I make 4 POSTs to the same php file with different parameters and I want them to be synchronized

Comment: @Kam why do you need to make *four* posts?

Comment: because each time I call I update a different div element. You are right I can probably fix this by passing jason array

Comment: what's bad in synchro calls?

Comment: @Kam even in that case it wouldn't necessarily need to be synchronous, but it would be a better idea to get all four results at once

Comment: @Kam it locks up the browser

Comment: I think `$.ajaxSetup({async: false});` will block all ajax requests. I would avoid this.

Comment: @guettli agreed that you don't want to block ajax requests and this is a bad idea, but I was just explaining how to do it.